# Ansible when compare two variables

Tags: python, ansible

In `vars/main.yml` I have this:

```
user_data:
  service:
    name: hello1
    description: abc
    update:
      name: hello
      version: 1
```

In playbook I try to write when condition:

```
      - name: "stop all"
        systemd:
          name: "does not matter.service"
          state: stopped
        when: user_data.service.update is defined
```

It works.

When i write this task with `update` in when condition:

```
      - name: "stop all"
        systemd:
          name: "does not matter.service"
          state: stopped
        when: user_data.service.update.name is defined
```

It is skipped

All variables are setted in `vars/main.yml` or passed using extra var as a JSON.

What's wrong?

Comment: In your first try, your when condition should not contain jinja2 template markers: `when: "user_data.service.update.name != user_data.service.name"`. In your second try, you skip because `user_data.service.update.name` is obviously undefined. How do you load your vars/main.yml file into your playbook ? Is it through a role ? I don't see `user_data.service.modules` defined anywhere...

Comment: @Zeitounator i update my question. please look at this

Comment: `vars/main.yml` at the same level of a playbook will not be loaded automatically and should be included in your playbook with `vars_files:`. It is only loaded when it is a directory inside a role that you are using. Are you sure you are loading those vars correctly ?

Comment: I found where the problem is. Drafting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update` is actually a reserved word (i.e. built-in method of dict object). See the following playbook. You can define an `update` hash key in yaml but I did not find any way to retrieve it back correctly. The only solution I see at this point (besides firing a ticket on github ansible project) is to rename your hash key to something else.

The following playbook

```
---
- name: Debug that tricky thing
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    user_data:
      service:
        name: hello1
        description: abc
        update:
          name: hello
          version: 1

  tasks:
    - name: Show the full var
      debug:
        var: user_data

    - name: Try to how the update hash test1
      debug:
        var: user_data.update

    - name: Try to how the update hash test2
      debug:
        var: user_data["update"]
```

Results in

```
PLAY [Debug that tricky thing] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show the full var] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "user_data": {
        "service": {
            "description": "abc",
            "name": "hello1",
            "update": {
                "name": "hello",
                "version": 1
            }
        }
    }
}

TASK [Try to how the update hash test1] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "user_data.update": "<built-in method update of dict object at 0x7fc5d9256630>"
}

TASK [Try to how the update hash test2] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "user_data[\"update\"]": "<built-in method update of dict object at 0x7fc5d9256630>"
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is python interpreter does not understand the object format in the main.yml file. Convert that object in a format that can be understood by the interpreter. Usually, python objects are represented in the form of a dictionary, so you could convert it to something like this:

user_data = {'service': {'attr': 1, 'some_a': 'abc'}, 'update':{'name: 'hello', 'version': 1} }

Comment: i did not mention it, but in vars/main.yml may not be theese variable, they are passed using extra var in JSON

Comment: Either way, the user_data needs to be in a dictionary format before checking for the condition, or at least a function module that returns the data from the source(JSON). Check on this https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: The first error comes from how the `when` condition is written (it should not contain jinja2 template markers). The `vars/main.yml` yaml file is completely valid and should load without any problems in ansible.